# Error trying to run my compiled program in Java

Tags: java, runtime-error

This is my first program, and my first attempt at running it. I am on Ubuntu.

Source Code:

```
class printTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

And this is the error I get when I try to run it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: printTest : 
                                               Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: printTest. Program will exit.


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
Press return to continue
```

EDIT: Okay, this is my JRE version:
    owner@ubuntu:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.4) (6b24-1.11.4-1ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
owner@ubuntu:~$

But my javac version is: 1.7.0_03

Answer (score 2):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
```

You have runtime JVM version different from Compile time JVM version.

Make sure your classpath points to same JVM version as compile time.

Comment: Is that something to do with the JRE?

Comment: I was just about to post my answer when the one new answer message popped up xD

Comment: Yes, check your classpath and make sure the JAVA_HOME paths are pointing to same JRE. Are you using any IDE?

Comment: @Nambari Yes, well I am using Geany.

Comment: I would suggest check JAVA_HOME settings for that IDE. I never worked on it, so I couldn't point you exact location. There may be something related to compiler version setting also, make sure compiler setting also correct.

Comment: @Nambari Is 'Startup Path' what I want to set? In Geany that is?

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between java version on which you are compiling source code and java version on which you are executing source code.

`You are compiling in java 7 and executing in lesser version you need to set JAVA_HOME to java7 only.`

[Here is how to set JAVA_HOME on Ubantu.](http://www.zimbio.com/the+ubuntu+guy/articles/82/How+set+JAVA_HOME+environment+variable+Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your program in a IDE. It is much easier because it shows you the errors in your code and you can easily compile it from the same program. 
Here is the site where you can download a good one 
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-and-dsl-developers/junosr2